# Google reporting that country subdomains (English) are all canonical to the default despite hreflang and lack of canonical tags

Tags: subdomain, hreflang

We have some serieus issues with google not indexing language subdomains. It keeps marking the main domain as canonical prefered.I did some research on the matter, the code below was the result (that for now is not working)

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://airtrackfactory.com/shop/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ie" href="https://ie.airtrackfactory.com/shop/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-uk" href="https://uk.airtrackfactory.com/shop/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="https://us.airtrackfactory.com/shop/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-za" href="https://za.airtrackfactory.com/shop/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="https://au.airtrackfactory.com/shop/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-nz" href="https://nz.airtrackfactory.com/shop/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ca" href="https://ca.airtrackfactory.com/shop/" />
```

A screenshot of our webmaster toolkit https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o1X4.png

The subdomains should be indexed by google as country specific, but currently it is only indexing the main domain (without prefix). We really thought with thishreflang setup this "problem" would be gone.

Comment: Are you using canonical tag? is there any noindex tag or the subdomains are blocked by robots.txt?

Comment: Hi Emirodgar, Yes we are using a canonical tag
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://uk.airtrackfactory.com/shop/"/>`

And we allow indexation, so no blocking in robots.txt `view-source:https://uk.airtrackfactory.com/robots.txt`

There is NO no-index tag

Comment: Regardless of what search console is reporting, does Google show your UK site when somebody searches from the UK on `google.co.uk`?   You might need to use a UK proxy server to test that out.   It's been a while since I've worked for a client that has multiple country targeted English sites (before Search Console started reporting canonical).  In my experience Google would show the correct country URLs when people did searches from those countries even when it detected the content was duplicate.   It may just be a Search Console reporting issue.